# The Calculation of the Volume of a Photon Sphere around a Black Hole

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, photons, astrophysics

So, I chose this question for my chemistry assignment which is "How many moles of photons will it take to fill up the volume of the photon sphere around Sagittarius A". I realized there is no actual question or solution as to how to calculate the volume for the photon sphere, so my theory is to find the Schwarzschild Radius of the Event Horizon from the point of Singularity (Rs[s-ev]) then calculate Schwarzschild Radius from the point of Singularity to the Photon Sphere. We can identify the size difference in them. Then we calculate the volume of the event horizon. Now we know the radius and volume of the event horizon, and radius of the photon sphere. To find volume, we can use size difference to calculate volume (for example: an apple has a volume of 2 cubic feet, 2 inches in radius, a banana has a radius of 4, so what's volume --> well, from radius of 2 to 4, volume must go from 2 to 4).

I spoke to my physics teacher and he mentioned how I would need to find the size of an actual photon. So my question is, would the calculation to find the photon sphere work and does it make sense? Also, any theories on the size of a photon.

Comment: Photons are Bosons. They can overlap. Two beams of photons pass through each other without collisions. They are not like atoms, which are Fermions and cannot overlap. Photons do not fill up a volume in the same sense as atoms do.

Comment: @mmesser314, so if photons don't fill up like atoms, what kind of volume does a photon sphere have? I mean is it a volume that defines and limits space or is it boundless? Also, can't I have a large number of identical photons in the same identical region in space because of Bose-Einstein condensation.

Comment: Here is a video that may help. It mentions what the photon sphere is. [How to Understand What Black Holes Look Like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUyH3XhpLTo). The volume is not straightforward because spacetime is curved near a black hole. You cannot use $V = 4/3\pi r^3$.

Comment: You can have many identical photons in the same place. This is how a laser works. A photon hits an excited atom in the laser medium. The medium is stimulated to give off a photon identical to the one that hit. The laser cavity fills with identical photons. This forms the laser beam. See the Hyperphysics page on [Quantum Properties of Light](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/optmod/qualig.html#c2) or the RP Photonics article on [Stimulated Emission](https://www.rp-photonics.com/stimulated_emission.html) and linked articles

Comment: @mmesser314, okay thank you!

Comment: It sounds like an interesting project. Too bad that quantum mechanics and general relativity make it harder than you might think.

Comment: “*Now we know the radius and volume of the event horizon*” - Yes we do - it is zero: https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734 - “*There is a zero volume inside a black hole in any Schwarzschild time slice of a Schwarzschild black hole spacetime*”. - All you need to do for your project is to change the limits of the integral in the volume formula there.